# Incomplete final line found error when reading url using readLines() in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to read the html content of a url using the readLines() function in R. However, I am getting a `"incomplete final line found"` warning message as shown below? How can I skip the final line in such a case? Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

```
x <- readLines("https://in.finance.yahoo.com/industries/technology")

Warning message:
In readLines("https://in.finance.yahoo.com/industries/technology") :
  incomplete final line found on 'https://in.finance.yahoo.com/industries/technology'
```

Comment: It's not an error, it is a warning. Check the data you got if the contain the information you want. Also have a look at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/readLines

Comment: Although the URL i provided was just an example, the actual url I am trying to read (which is my company's internal url) is throwing this warning message even if I fix the `n` value. The page has ~1000 lines but `readLines` seems to be reading only the first line. Was wondering how to fix this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Most files are missing an End of Line marker like a new line below, so I would just use warn=FALSE.

```
cat("abc\ndef\nhij", file="test.txt")
readLines( "test.txt")
# [1] "abc" "def" "hij"
# Warning message:
# In readLines("test.txt") : incomplete final line found on 'test.txt'
readLines( "test.txt", warn=FALSE)
# [1] "abc" "def" "hij"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris S. The `warn=FALSE` option eliminated the warning message. Would you happen to know any other way by which I can scrape web pages faster other than `readLines()`? Sorry for diverting from my original question.

Comment: I'd skip `readLines` since most web scraping packages like `rvest` can read URLs directly.  I think you should only need `readLines` for  the XML package and  secure https like `xmlParse(readLines(my_https_url, warn=FALSE))`

Comment: Thanks again. I do not have much experience with web scraping although I know we have packages like `RCurl`, `rvest`, `httr` etc for this. I have been getting some SSL Error for the same and was not able to figure out why. I found `readLines` to be very easy to work with when it comes to extracting html content.

Comment: I added an empty newline to the end of my `.env` file and the warning went away.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered this issue many time. Most of the cases the following solution helped:
"Opene the file in the editor, pressed "Enter" and saved".

However there was one time where this solution didn't work.
So I set the option warn=FALSE in readLines() and the final result only stored few lines from the entire file. So here is what I did.

1. I ran readLines with warn="FALSE".

   `data <- readLines(file, warn=FALSE)`
2. I checked the length of "data"

   ```
   length(data)
   7258
   ```
3. I opened the file and went to the line number mentioned above i.e line number 7258. There was a weird looking character in the next line, which I removed. And removed that character from many other lines from the same file. And saved it.

I ran the readLines function again and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I used readLines with html files. What I did was to add empty line to the end of the file, that will probably fix your issue.

Before:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO1xb.png

After:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Eqr7.png

Comment: Welcome to SO Yongye Tan. Please don't post code as an image, because of [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). It is much better if code is placed inside codeblocks. Thanks.